# How to set yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage in Cloudera

Tags: cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I want to set `yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage` for YARN cluster, and i use CDH 5.3.3 to manage it.

In cloudera manager web console, i did not find the configuraions of YARN has this property.

I tried to add a property in `yarn-site.xml` on all nodes and restarted the cluster, but it did not work.

In YARN configuration web page, i found the default value of yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage was 90.0, and it was defined in `yarn-default.xml`. But there was no such file on all nodes.
[image]

How could i set the property for YARN cluster?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fianlly i found the right way to set this property for Cloudera YARN.
You should find the NodeManager Advanced Configuration Snippet for yarn-site.xml and add a property configuration just like this:
[image]